# PowerQuery: Refreshing a Table query whilst the Data Source file is open

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I have an excel workbook containing a table  that is linked to numerous Data Source files via PowerQuery. There is a high likelihood that the a user will be in the Data Source files updating them. Is it possible for me to refresh my table using powerquery whilst the Data Source Files are open by another user. I keep getting the message:

[DataSource.Error] The process cannot access the file '......' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: If you are reading Excel files from a folder, then you should filter out files with a name starting with "~".

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out files with a name starting with "~".

Comment: Can you give more info about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic when trying to work out how to do the same thing.  Just in case anyone finds this in the future, I'll mention how I applied MarcelBeug's solution.

Code was this

```
let Source = Folder.Files("MyFilePathHere\"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
```

Changed to

```
let Source = Folder.Files("MyFilePathHere\"),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Name], "~$")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Custom", each 
Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
```

I made the change via the GUI editor using a Text Filter on the file name.  The filter was 'does not begin with' and the value was '~$'.